# Why $0$ (zero) is a purely imaginary number?

Tags: complex-numbers, definition

I was reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-Hermitian_matrix) Wikipedia article and found that $0$ is a purely imaginary number. Why? Is it because $i0=0$? So zero is the only number which is real as well as purely imaginary? Any explanations on this please?

Comment: I think any number with no real part is called a purely imaginary number So  here since the real part is zero then it is purely imaginary

Comment: Or maybe because $0$ is the only intersecting point of real and imaginary axes.

Comment: The referenced link is slightly self-contradicting as it first says "... are all purely imaginary or zero", then "... zero is also considered purely imaginary". The second expression is better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is just a matter of definitions.

Let $z$ be a complex number. Then, $z$ may be written (uniquely) as $z = a + bi$.

$a$ is said to be the real part of $z$.

$b$ is said to be the imaginary part of $z$.

$z$ is said to be a purely imaginary number if its real part is equal to $0$.

Hence, $0$ is a purely imaginary number because its real part is $0$.

Comment: At the same time, it can also be said purely real, real, imaginary or complex (!).